# Anytime js datepicker error

Tags: javascript, anytime

I have a problem with anytime.js ;
The input field exists

> <input type="text" value="" name="step_dimension_value" >

this is how i called the plugin:

```
jQuery('input[name="step_dimension_value"]').AnyTime_picker({ 
    format: "%H:%i", 
    labelTitle: "Hora",
    labelHour: "Hora", 
    labelMinute: "Minuto" 
});
```

The error is (from Firebug console):

```
" TypeError: off is null [Break On This Error]
var left = off.left; " in anytime.js?ver=1 (line 3062)
```

can you please help me ?

*** EDIT ***

I think i have the answer:

In my opinion there is a problem in the anytime.js datepicker;
Fortunately it can be very easily worked around.

**How to reproduce**:
 - If the call to anytime picker is done using jquery selector,
(Like : jQuery('input[name="step_dimension_value"]').AnyTime_picker(....))
and the input does not have an id, the error will happen;

**Workaround**:
 - add an id to the input element; 
I tested it and this works.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bug, it's by design, and mentioned in the Troubleshooting Tips near the end of the project home page here:

[www.ama3.com/anytime/#fixBehavior](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#fixBehavior)